# Basic Windows Programming question in VS2005

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2005, messagebox

I created a win32 console application (without enable precompiled header option).
And now my source code as this, there is two compiler errors.

```
// AFormattingMsgBox.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"


//int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    int cxScreen, cyScreen;

    cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    MessageBoxPrintf(TEXT("ScrnSize"), TEXT("The screen is %i pixels wide by %i pixels high."), cxScreen, cyScreen);

    return 0;
}


int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(TCHAR * szCaption, TCHAR * szFormat, int x, int y)
{
    TCHAR szBuffer [1024];
    va_list pArgList;

    va_start(pArgList, szFormat);

    _vsntprintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR), 
                szFormat, pArgList);

    va_end(pArgList);

    return MessageBox(NULL, szBuffer, szCaption, 0);

}
```

Compiler Errors.

> error C3861: 'MessageBoxPrintf': identifier not found
>
> error C2365: 'MessageBoxPrintf' : redefinition; previous definition was 'formerly
> unknown identifier

How can I fix the errors. Thanks for your reading and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put the function MessageBoxPrintf before the WinMain function or add a prototype before winMain. You add a prototype by entering the following line:

```
int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(TCHAR * szCaption, TCHAR * szFormat, int x, int y);
```

Comment: Followed your suggestion, but still show link error:  *error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup*

Comment: And then I changed `int APIENTRY WinMain(...)` to `int _tmain(...)`. It works now. Thanks.